# Property accessor of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

As mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), Property names must be strings.

For code,

```
var foo = {unique_prop: 1}, obj = {};
obj[foo] = 'value';
console.log(obj[foo]);
```

In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), it says,

*In the SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine, this string would be "['object Object']".*

How does the property(string literal) of object type `obj` is stored like?

Is the property stored as `"['unique_prop 1']"` ?

Comment: Just log `obj`, and you'll see ( the key will literally be `[object Object]`).

Comment: @Teemu `console.log(object);` , displays,  `Object { [object Object]: "value" }`

Comment: Yep, there you can see the key: `[object Object]`, not `['unique_prop 1']`. Did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Teemu  If `bar = {unique_prop : 2};` and then I need to insert second item in `obj` with `bar` as property? What would be property look like?

Comment: You can't, it would override the the first-one since having the same key, i.e. that would just be a re-assignment.

Comment: @Teemu How come Javascript doesn't allow me to insert second item in `obj`, when property is of `object` type? Does this make sense?

Comment: Umh... You said in your post that "this string would be "['object Object']"", hence no matter which object is used as a key, it's always converted to a string, i.e. `[object Object]`. Keys in JS objects are always strings, if you're trying to use some other type, the value is implicitely converted to a string. Try to test with a function reference, you'll might get surprised ...

Comment: In ES6 you might use the new [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) collection type that accepts anything as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a property on an object from a variable, JS engine calls `toString()` method on a passed value. The actual value for the key is decided [from its type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString()_to_detect_object_class).

You can check this behaviour yourself:

```js
var foo = {};
foo.toString = function() {
  return "toString";
}
var bar = {};
bar[foo] = "prop value";


for (var k in bar) {
  console.log(k);
}
```

Comment: When you say `foo.toString`, are you overriding `Object.toString()`? Is it `foo.prototype.toString`?

Comment: @overexchange: No, it's `foo.toString()`. Only functions have `prototype` property because functions can be used as constructors. Objects don't have `prototype` property but they do have prototypes (their constructor's `prototype` property).

Comment: Object.prototype. And Object is a function.